# Sentiment analyst - python TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, numpy

I want to do the NLP preprocessing for the tweets, however I have not been able to do the part of removing the @, lowercase, and bag of words. I get the following error :

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import re

def clean_data(review):
    return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", review).split())

def analize_data(review):
        analysis = TextBlob(clean_data(review))
        if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
            return 1
        elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
            return 0
        else:
            return -1

df = np.array([ analize_data(review) for review in df['full_text'] ])
display(df.head(20))
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full error stack?

Comment: hello, the code of the error is : df['SA'] = np.array([ analize_data(review) for review in text['full_text'] ]) 
display(text.head(20))

Comment: <ipython-input-51-c469ba1bd5ad> in <module>()
----> 1 df = np.array([ analize_data(review) for review in df['full_text'] ])
      2 display(df.head(20))

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    192     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
    193     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 194     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    195 
    196 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object